# how i can differentiate between a gesture and a touch in spriteKit and swift?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

i have two functions, one is activated when i touch the scene and another one when i make a gesture down, but when i make a gesture the scene detect a touch and execute both functions

```
class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    /* Setup your scene here */

    // physics & collisions
    physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0.0, 0.0)
    physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self

    // Swipe down
    let swipeDown:UISwipeGestureRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("swipedDown:"))
    swipeDown.direction = .Down
    view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeDown)

}

//MARK: Swipes
func swipedDown(sender:UISwipeGestureRecognizer){
    //first function
    swipeDown()
}

//MARK: Touches
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    /* Called when a touch begins */

    for touch in touches {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
        // second function
        attack()
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `touchesBegan`, try using a tap gesture (`UITapGestureRecognizer`) for attack action.

This should not be necessary but if you still get conflict between swipe and tap, make the tap gesture depend on swipe's failure using `requireGestureRecognizerToFail` to ensure that a tap is not detected during a swipe.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this

```
var swiped = Bool()
func swipedDown(sender:UISwipeGestureRecognizer){
     //first function
     swipeDown()
     swiped = true 

}

Override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
/* Called when a touch begins */

     for touch in touches {
         let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
         // second function
         if swiped == false {
               attack()
         }
     }
}


 override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?)  {
      for touch in touches {
            swiped = false
       }

}
```

Hope this helps.